# Read query string parameter value in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, query-string, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have passed one parameter to report server url.

```
http://<your server>/ReportServer?/<folder>/<reportname>&UserID=Name
```

How can I read `UserID` value in report.

**Or**

How can I print this value in any of the textbox to check what is passed to it?
For example: Above url should show 'Name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with my parameter `UserId`.

I have set it as Internal that's why it was set to default value `blank space` instead of passed parameter `UserId` value. (Now I am using `hidden`)

***Note: Report parameters are case sensitive so in my case it must be `UserId`***

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I think you've figured this out already, but all you should need is the parameter `UserId` to exist on the report and it will get its value from the query string.

A couple other problems that can crop up when trying to pass a parameter:

- Report parameters are case sensitive
- Report parameters with visibility set to `Internal` can't be passed a value through URL

See also: [Pass a report parameter within a URL on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the Built-In SSRS fields ...

Try using `Expression -> Built-In-Fields -> UserId` should work in this case, if I understood your question correctly...

OR

Try manipulating the report server URL. Provided below one for example ...

```
=mid(Globals!ReportServerUrl , InStr(Globals!ReportServerUrl,"&UserID=")+8)
```

Comment: actually it will not show the query string parameter value of userID. For example I am passing `Pedram` but showing `SERVER1\PC1`

Comment: From where you are passing Pedram ? Is it defined by you ?

Comment: from web application in query string. btw can you please delete your answer as I wanted to this delete this question. it is due to my silly mistake I wan not getting parameter name in report.

Comment: It is ok. Check for the updated answer. This should work in this scenario. It would help others also...